# My PSU vibrates audibly. Do I need to send it back?

Tags: power-supply

I have a be quiet! Pure Power L8 530W, which has been working flawlessly for some time now (can't remember, perhaps 9 months?). Recently, it started making a low, vibrating noise which I can hear right through the chassis, and in fact right through my headset, too.

I know it's coming from the PSU, because when I touch it, I can feel the vibration (which I can't on any other component). Touching it to perhaps stabilize it does nothing.

The question is, is this something common with a potentially easy solution? Or is the PSU (or its fan) faulty, and I need to try to get a replacement?

I have unfortunately lost the warranty.

Comment: Most likely would be laminations in the transformer, which can sometimes vibrate.  It's harmless but annoying.

Comment: While harmless they advertise the product as being quite, "Exceptionally quiet operation achieved through an array of careful optimizations", if its under warranty take advantage of that fact.

Comment: If only I had the warranty :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vibration is coming from the cooling fan. The most common cause is the bearing on the fan slowly lose their lubrication over time which leads to a bearing failure.

Without knowing what kind of power supply fan is installed by that brand, I would say it would be best to buy a new power supply.

For me, a PSU is a bit too close to the vitals of the system and it's components not to mention 120v AC to mess around with. If you are confident in your repair abilities, you could attempt to open the casing and possibly replace the fan. Usually they use a normal 80mm or 120mm fan.

You really don't want the fan to fail because the power supply could harm all the other components in your system. I usually buy Seasonic or Corsair PSUs as they are very reliable; they also have high efficiency models. I think Tom's Hardware did a review on them.